# Select specified row from multiple rows returned by select

Tags: sqlite

I have a select statement which returns multiple rows.  I need to select a particular one of these rows.  I would like to write something like

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM table WHERE x IS y ) WHERE row_in_selected_rows IS n;
```

Is this possible?

Note that I cannot use the rowid from the original table, because i have the index of the required row in the rows returned from the first select statement, not the index in the original table.

Comment: What do you mean by `row_in_selected_rows IS n`, is it some kind of row number? If yes, how is the numbering defined inside the query: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE x IS y`?

Comment: If the the first select returns 5 rows, then I need to select, for example, the 4th row of the 5 returned.

Comment: answer 1 is right
you just have to try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select col1, col2, ....
from (
  SELECT *, row_number() over() rn 
  FROM table 
  WHERE x IS y
) t
where t.rn = 4
```

but this way the order of the rows returned from the query is not defined, so the 4th row could be any row.
 
The correct way would be:

```
select col1, col2, ....
from (
  SELECT *, row_number() over(order by somecolumn) rn 
  FROM table 
  WHERE x IS y
) t
where t.rn = 4
```

You could also use `OFFSET` with `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM table WHERE x IS y ) 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3;
```

which skips the *first* 3 rows and returns only the 4th, but again `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` should be used with `ORDER BY`, like:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM table WHERE x IS y ) 
ORDER BY somecolumn
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3;
```

Comment: This looks interesting.  I am not familiar with "window functions".  Just found this https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html

Comment: LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3 seems like the way to go - I am familiar with these!

Comment: Window functions are also very useful. Check this also: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/ and the links inside the page.

Comment: LIMIT 1 OFFSET row_in_selected_rows works well.  Thanks